# Actualizar/Agregar un documento en MongoDB en java

Tags: java, json, base-de-datos, mongodb, insert

Mi esquema es el siguiente:

```
{
  "isbn": {
    "$numberLong": "9509970667528"
  },
  "titulo": "Operación masacre",
  "nombre_del_autor": "Rodolfo Walsh",
  "editorial": "de bolsillo",
  "tipo_genero": "Narrativo",
  "tipo_subgenero": "Policiaca",
  "stock": 49,
  "precio": 10330,
  "vendidos": [
    {
      "id_boleta": 164413,
      "rut_cliente": 173238604,
      "fecha": 250321,
      "hora": 1745,
      "tipo_de_entrega": "presencial",
      "cantidad": 1,
      "precio_total": 10330
    }
  ]
}
```

Como puedo añadir ventas a vendidos?

Este es mi clase principal

```
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Bookstop");
    MongoCollection<Libros> collection = 
    database.getCollection("Libros",Libros.class);
```

Donde tengo mis 2 clases POJOs Libros,Vendidos con sus setters y getters

Necesito solo ir añadiendo a vendidos no reemplazar ni eliminar

Comment: ¿Ya checaste esto https://stackoverflow.com/q/15436542/8838721?

Comment: lo estuve viendo pero no logro traspasarlo a mi codigo, no comprendo si tengo que crear un documento nuevo y reemplazar o tengo que insertar en el array

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir tus POJO's para ver cómo los tienes implementados?

Comment: Ya he logrado hacerlo